# Can I manage color resources like this?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Im tired to type like `ContextCompat(context, color.red)`. Is there any simple way to get color code from colors.xml?

I'm beginner of kotlin. I've try like this but I'm not sure this is the best. And can I use lazy like that?

colors.xml

```xml
<color name="skyblue">#00bcda</color>
<color name="blue">#4283e6</color>
<color name="green">#66bb6a</color>
<color name="orange">#ffa726</color>
<color name="red">#ff6b4e</color>
<color name="pink">#ffa5a5</color>
```

ColorManager.kt

```
class ColorManager(val context: Context) {
    private fun getColor(id: Int) = lazy { ContextCompat.getColor(context, id) }

    val skyblue by getColor(color.skyblue)
    val blue by getColor(color.blue)
    val green by getColor(color.green)
    val orange by getColor(color.orange)
    val red by getColor(color.red)
    val pink by getColor(color.pink)
}
```

Use The Code

```
val colors by lazy { ColorManager(this) }
...
colors.skyblue // this code return integer color code
```

Comment: *Please note* that making value lazy impacts on runtime, because compiler has to do extra efforts to resolve lazy values from java byte code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below **extension function** to retrieve color using `ContextCompat`:

```
fun Context?.getResourceColor(@ColorRes color: Int): Int {
    var finalColor: Int? = null // Create local color variable
    this?.let { // check if context is null or not
        finalColor = ContextCompat.getColor(it, color) // Retrive resource color using ContextCompat
    }
    return finalColor ?: Color.TRANSPARENT // return default color if resource color not found
}
```

And now use it in any file with context like this : `context.getResourceColor(R.color.someColor)`

Comment: Thanks! Nice To use.